# Angular 10 behavior subject returns null after calling .next(value) method

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I've been pulling my hairs out trying to figure out what is the reason that my user value is null after login.

this is my login page. it calls an api and gets the result as seen below:

[image]

and this is my authentication service:

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  public user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
    this.userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')));
    this.user = this.userSubject.asObservable();
  }
  public get userValue(): User {
    return this.userSubject.value;
  }

  GetUsername(): string {
    if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser') != null)
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).UserName;
    return null;
  }
  login(username: string, password: string) {

    return this.http.post<any>(`${Statics.ApiUrl}users/authenticate`, { Username: username, Password: password }, { responseType: "json" })
      .pipe(map(user => {
        debugger;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
        this.userSubject.next(user);
        return user;
      }));
  }

  logout() {
    //remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    this.userSubject.next(null);
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

  signUp(RegisterModel: RegisterModel): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>(`${Statics.ApiUrl}users/signup`, RegisterModel, { responseType: "json" });
  }
  verifyUserPhone(username: string, password: string, verificationCode: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.put<User>(Statics.ApiUrl + 'users/verifyUserPhone', { username, password, verificationCode }, { responseType: "json" });
  }
}
```

And here is my authguard:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    ) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
      debugger;
      const user = this.authenticationService.userValue;
      var token_expiration=new Date(user?.TokenExpirartion);
      var now=new Date();
        if (user && token_expiration>now) {
            // check if route is restricted by role
            if (route.data.roles && route.data.roles.indexOf(user.role) === -1) {
                // role not authorised so redirect to home page
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
                return false;
            }

            // authorized so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.authenticationService.logout();
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return false;
    }
}
```

i login and i get the user data and i store it the local storage but my authguard never lets route to be activated because authentication service always return user NULL.If I only refresh the page then it works. and as for logout it does not logout user untill I refresh the page.

see it below:

[image]

this is my login button ts code :

```
this.AuthenticationService.login(this.username, this.password)
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe({
    next: () => {

      // get return url from query parameters or default to home page
      const returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
      this.router.navigateByUrl(returnUrl);
    },
    error: error => {
      this.error = error;
      this.submited = false;
    }
  });
```

When authguard checks for userSubject after loging-in it returns null. no matter how many times I login it will return null unless I refresh the page.
only then userSubject gets evaluated. I don't know what to do. I can't login to my site. i have to login and then refresh the page to make authguard work.

after refreshing page i have the value:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your services provided in root? If not, you may be getting multiple instances.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the auth service takes some time to fetch data, and by then the route is already rejected as it got null.

You can try adding some wait before approving/rejecting a route

Comment: where exactly should I put a timer?

Comment: No, It didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that your authguard is sync, and canActivate is called before user is actually loaded. You can fix this if your canActivate will return observable of boolean, not boolean.
First you need to add function that will return observable of user if it was alreay loaded, and load user oservise, something like this:

```
public getOrFetchUser(): Observable<User> {
   // please note that we return observable in both cases
   return this.userSubject.value ? of(this.userSubject.value) : this.login();
}
```

and then change your canActivate guard to this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
return this.authenticationService.getOrFetchUser().pipe(
   map((user) => {
      console.log('user, ', user);
      // change return to your validation logic
      return true; 
});
```